# Long USB cable for iPad kiosk?

Tags: ipad, charging, accessories

Does Apple or anyone else sell iDevice cables that are several feet or several yards long? I'm making an iPad Kiosk and need to keep it powered.

I'd be even happier if someone could point me to a "smart" charger which knows when to stop charging and when to start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Griffin makes a 10 ft USB dock cable and it is available in the [Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H1826ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE&mco=MTg4Mjk0Nzk)

Answer (score 0):

The smarts for the charging is in the device, not the charger.  At least for iPads and virtually all USB-charging devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the power cord extension cable onto the iPad's power brick. That will also add 6ft of length to make your Griffin+power brick extension length 16ft.